# Jenkins deploy www-data and jenkins user permissions

Tags: laravel, deployment, jenkins

I've set up a basic Laravel deploy workflow with Jenkins. Everything works fine except the chwon / chmod commands that run after the build.

> chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/www/html/projectname/storage/framework/sessions/dc164af49acb0c9229fff8d75fb381a87e4bb3fa’: Operation not permitted
>
> chown: changing ownership of ‘/var/www/html/projectname/node_modules/resolve/test/node_path/y/bbb/index.js’: Operation not permitted

I've checked that those files ownership belongs to www-data user. But how can I change the builded file ownership or how can I set up Jenkins to build files with another user?

I've already tried setting the user variable in etc/default/jenkins file but that does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

- See the output of `$whoami` in `configure -> Build -> Execute shell` section and see the permission of file by `ls -l <path/to/file>`. If the `jenkins` (let $whoami=jenkins) user doesn't have the enough permission then add the user to `/etc/sudoers` and use `sudo` followed by `chown/chmod`.

Comment: I'm going to try it on monday and post my results. Thanks!

Comment: Still no luck with that even with sudo.